# When does format actually print in Common Lisp?

Tags: format, common-lisp

I have the following Common Lisp code:

```
(defun micro-read-eval-print ()
    (format t "Micro > ")
    (let ((form (read-line)))))
```

When I run it, I get the following:

```
CL-USER> (micro-read-eval-print)
(m-quote a)
Micro > NIL
```

Note that I typed in "(m-quote a)", while the Lisp interpreter output "Micro > NIL".

Now, I would have expected these events to happen in the reverse order.  I would have expected "Micro > " to have been printed first since the format statement comes first.  Why isn't it printed first?  And what do I have to do to make sure it is printed first?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try adding

```
(defun micro-read-eval-print ()
    (format t "Micro > ")
    (finish-output)
    (let ((form (read-line)))))
```

I believe you are encountering the buffering of standard io (stdio) which, in C, is commonly bypassed via `fflush()` in that language.

`finish-output` appears to be the Common Lisp equivalent of C standard library's `fflush`.

Comment: Right, implementations may use buffered IO streams and don't need to force output after a format or before a read. So for portable code one has to call something like force-output or finish-output.