# LISP: (format) prints only after successful (read)

Tags: format, lisp, common-lisp, bufferedoutputstream

I'm going through the book **ANSI Common Lisp** by Paul Graham, and there's this example:

```lisp
(defun ask-number ()
  (format t "Please enter a number. ")
  (let ((val (read)))
       (if (numberp val)
           val
           (ask-number))))
```

It should behave like this:

---

$ (ask-number)

Please enter a number. **a**

Please enter a number. **(ho hum)**

Please enter a number. **52**

52

---

But when I try it (SBCL 1.0.55), it doesn't print the **format** string until successful **read**:

---

$ (ask-number)

**a**

**(ho hum)**

**52**

Please enter a number. Please enter a number. Please enter a number.

52

---

Where's the error? How to make it behave the intended way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is an often asked question. There are possibly duplicates of this on Stackoverflow.

The output can be buffered.

You then need to call the standard Common Lisp function `FINISH-OUTPUT` to force the IO system to write any pending output.

After that, read.

Comment: Aha, buffering! Thanks, adding (finish-output) after the (format ...) line solves this problem.

Comment: Also, you were right about the duplicates. I didn't check similar questions - my bad. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426312/when-does-format-actually-print-in-common-lisp